# Question about Lemma 3.15 in Real Analysis; Modern Techniques and Their Applications by Folland, G. B.,

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

**Lemma.** Let $C$ be a collection of open balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $U =\cup_{B\in C} B$. If $c<m(U)$, there exist disjoint $B_1,...,B_k\in C$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{k}m(B_j)> 3^{-n}c$.

Here $m$ is the lebesgue measure.

In the proof, it first picks up one compact $K\subset U$ with $m(K)>c$ and finitely many of the balls $A_1,...,A_p$ in $C$ to cover $K$. Let $B_1$ be the largest of the $A_j$'s (which have the maximal radius), let $B_2$ be the largest of the $A_j$'s that are disjoint from $B_1$, and so on until the list of $A_j$'s is exhausted after $k$ steps. If $B_i = B(x_i,r_i)$, put $B_i^*=B(x_i,3r_i)$. Then $K\subset \cup_{i=1}^{k}B_i^*$ and $c<\sum_{i=1}^k m(B_i^*) = 3^n\sum_{i=1}^k m(B_i)$.

**Question:** Suppose $C$ contains finitely many balls which are intersected with each other. Then how to do this construction.

Comment: The proof does not assume that $C$ is made up of disjoint balls. Nothing goes wrong if any two balls in $C$ intersect. When you cannot find a particular $B_i$ the proof just stops at that stage.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Okay, Got it now. Thank you!